# WriteS3-Object Specified value has invalid CRLF characters

Tags: aws-powershell

I am trying to write an automation script for a software release using :
AWS Tools version 4.1.10.0, from the Administrator PowerShell command window

The steps I follow:

1. Set my Aws IAM credentials using Set-AWSCredential
2. Run Write-S3Object

I have tried both writing a single object, and trying the entire directory.  I have also tried just a plan text file vs the msi I was trying to upload:

```
Write-S3Object -BucketName corerelease -Folder C:\GNC -KeyPrefix Release
```

PS

I have also tried following the powershell prompts:

```
C:\Dev\Release> Write-S3Object
cmdlet Write-S3Object at command pipeline position 1 Supply values for the following parameters: 
BucketName: release 
File: C:\Users\nmoer\source\repos\Forms\Setup\Release\Test.msi
```

Each time I receive back the message

```
Write-S3Object : Specified value has invalid CRLF characters. 
Parameter name: value At line:1 char:1 + Write-S3Object -BucketName release 
-Folder C:\Release -KeyPrefix Releas ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...eS3ObjectCmdlet:WriteS3ObjectCmdlet) [Write-S3Object], InvalidOperationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.S3.WriteS3ObjectCmdlet
```

If I try specifying even a plan text file in the root as well I encounter the same problem.  I must be blind to what the problem is.

Comment: Hello. Did you find a solution for this error ? I'm facing right now with a `Get-S3Object -BucketName $Bucket -KeyPrefix $KeyPrefix -Region us-east-1` command to download Nvidia GPU drivers for a g4dn instance